# Different methods to know unread messages under JavaMail

Tags: java, message, jakarta-mail

I just wonder, what is supposed to do exactly this:

```
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
Message messages[] = imap.folder_.search(ft);
int nbTotalUnreadMessages = messages.length;
// make a loop over the messsages to make some procedure
```

VS:

```
Message[] messages = imap.folder_.getMessages();
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    Message msg = messages[i];
    Flags flags = msg.getFlags();
    if ( flags.contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN) )
        continue;
    // proceed on the unseen message
}
```

The first version is lighting fast and just works.
The second version is 1/ slow 2/ doesn't work.
It's slow because it parses the entire folder and it doesn't work because as the documentation say, the only fact to get a message automatically suppose it has been seen.

So what damn, the first version is supposed to do internally? I'm just out of curiosity...
It is possible to obtain the flags of a message without obtaining the message itself?

Comment: Very Strange. The second method is indeed very slow, but if instead of retrieving all messages in Message[] I retrieve message one by one using imap.folder_.getMessage(i), it makes the method as fast as the first method that uses the native search(). The thing I still don't understand is why Flag.SEEN is automaticaly set whereas I don't get the content of a message according to the JavaMail documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is fast because the server searches through all the messages for you and returns the answer in one operation.

The second version is slow because you have to ask the server about each message.  The second version should give the same results as the first.  If it is not, I need more details, such as the protocol trace showing the difference between what's returned in the first case and what's returned in the second case.